# Build Go Project with jenkins and it report an error that did't report when building in cmd or goland

Tags: batch-file, go, jenkins

When I build a go project using a bat in jenkins, it reports an error:

```
go tool: no such tool "asm"
```

however, when I build the go project alone with cmd or goland, the error does't happen, Why this error happen?

the Command in Jenkins is

```
C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/build.bat
```

and the bat content is:

```
@echo off 
cd C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/GOPATH/src/Flipped_Server/main
go build main.go
xcopy main.exe "C:/Users/Administrator/Desktop/Flipped-Server" /s /e /c /y /h /r
echo "Succeed to build and deploy the flipped-Server"
```

Comment: *N. B.:* The Windows path separator is `\ `but not `/`; and you should use `cd /D C:\…` rather than `cd C:\…` in order to also change the drive in case you are currently working on another one…

Answer (score 0):

When I uncheck the option

```
Set up Go Programming language tools
```

It works! build Successfully